# Interaction with multi points

Tags: openlayers

I have multiple geometries with multi-points, and when I use script to select a feature, all features from multi-points are selected, but I want only clicked point.

My code to select points:`map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Select());`

[image][image]

Obs:I need use multi-point because I have so many points to draw, and this way is faster